# Stack Overflow event counter

Tags: discussion, statistics

I've written a counter of Stack Overflow events that the community might find interesting: http://popacular.com/analyticsoverflow. The data are updated by screen scraping Stack Overflow once every 15 minutes. In between the actual source updates, the numbers are just guessed based on the average rates.

Update: This is now using the SO API. StackApps entry: [analyticsoverflow - tracking question and answer counts over time](https://stackapps.com/questions/239/)

[image: Analytics Overflow shows posts per hour and can be sorted by tag]

Comment: Nice! I like it.

Comment: It's...Beautiful.

Answer (score 2):

Very good one, and those numbers are very close also, when I check it through [stackoverflow private beta api](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/stack-overflow-api-private-beta-starts/), You might want to join it also.

Note that beta api cannot be use on live site.